# How to create SQL table with limited entries?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I have a table that is used to store the latest actions the user did (like a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> for the program), but I want to limit this table to about 200 entries, and after that, every new entry would delete the oldest in the table.

Is there any option to make the table behave this way on SQL or do I need to add some code to the program to do it?

Comment: Just append records to the table and then use LIMIT 200 DESC to return the the latest entries.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this kind of idea before, but I've rarely seen a case where it was a *good* idea.

Your table would need these columns in addition to columns for the normal data.

- A column of type integer to hold the row number.
- A column of type timestamp (standard SQL timestamp) to hold the time of the last update.

The normal approach to limit this table to 200 rows would be to add a check constraint to the column of row numbers. For example, `CHECK (row_num between 1 and 200)`. MySQL doesn't enforce check constraints, so instead you'll need to use a foreign key reference to a table of row numbers (1 to 200).

All insert statements will need to determine whether the table is full, examine the time of the last update, and either a) insert a new row with a new row number, or b) delete the oldest row or overwrite it.

My advice? Renegotiate this requirement.

Comment: You can use a trigger on insert to do this, but it will be quite heavy on the performances. A delete query thrown regularly should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "200" is not a hard limit, in other words if the number of entries occasionally went over that by a small amount it would be OK...

Don't do the pruning on line, do it as an off line process, run as often as needed to keep the totals per user from not getting "too high".

For example, one such solution would be to fire the SQL that does that query every hour using `crontab`.